# How to change Jquery datatable sort icon color

Tags: jquery, datatables

Jquery Datatables sort icon is not properly visible, So how to change color of the sort icon, I want to change the color to black

Comment: maybe little more clearer? some examples, code, etc.?

Answer (score 11):

The sort icon which you mention in the Datatables is not a icon.. **It is a image**, [asc image](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/images/sort_asc.png) and [desc image](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/images/sort_desc.png). Hence you cannot change the color. But we can replace the image by another of your choice (similar image with your required color).

The image is set into the `th` by css

For sort asceding

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
    background-image: url(../images/sort_asc.png);
}
```

For sort descending

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
    background-image: url(../images/sort_desc.png);
}
```

You can **overwrite this rule by your custom CSS**.

```
#YourTableID thead .sorting_asc {
        background-image: url(../yourImage.png);
    }
```

same goes for desc image.. Hope this helps

---

Here is a working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

```css
#example thead .sorting_asc {
  background-image: url(http://www.miankoutu.com/uploadfiles/2015-9-24/2015924141740312.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
#example thead .sorting_desc {
  background-image: url(http://www.miankoutu.com/uploadfiles/2015-9-24/2015924141733340.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
#example .sorting {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Sort_both.svg/1000px-Sort_both.svg.png);
  background-size: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Engine</th>
      <th>Browser</th>
      <th>Platform</th>
      <th>version</th>
      <th>grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
      <td>Win 95+</td>
      <td>5.5</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trident</td>
      <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
      <td>Win 98+</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this above solution ,But still the problem is not solved

Comment: @Nutan Only issue would be that your css is not applied properly on the elements. may be prioritization issue or something.. Can you create a fiddle to show the issue?

Comment: @Nutan glad to help.. Can you accept the answer? as that will help future crowd with similar issue.