# Changing sorting icons in jQuery DataTables header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin with bootstrap 4 styling to draw my table. Below is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#my-table').DataTable({
   scrollY: '20vh',
   paging: false,
   dom: '<f>t',
      searching: false
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- dataTable -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <table class="table table-striped  table-hover table-fit" id="my-table">
      <thead class='thead-dark'>
        <tr>
          <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- dataTable -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I want to change the sorting arrows in the header to some other icons that look bigger. Something like this:

[image]

I have followed many answers: 
[How to change Jquery datatable sort icon color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037787/how-to-change-jquery-datatable-sort-icon-color)

[How to change the color of the sorting arrows in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851964/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-sorting-arrows-in-datatables)

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40100/replacing-original-sorting-icons-with-bootstrap-4

I have tried this in my css file:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting:before, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:before, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
  content: "\E253" !important;
}
```

But they don't change or the icons become distorted:

[image]

How do I do this? Or How can I make the original icons thicker?

Comment: Using a similar approach to yours, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902123/12567365) is an example where the default icons are replaced by arrows. Instead of those arrows, maybe you can use your triangles (e.g. [this](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25B2) or similar).

Comment: added solution @hydradon.

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#my-table').DataTable({
   scrollY: '20vh',
   paging: false,
   dom: '<f>t',
      searching: false
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 3%;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting:before, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:before, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:before, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
    right: 1em;
    content: "\02C6" !important;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting:after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after {
    right: 0.5em;
    content: "\02C7" !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- dataTable -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  </head>

  <body>

    <table class="table table-striped  table-hover table-fit" id="my-table">
      <thead class='thead-dark'>
        <tr>
          <th>Header
            
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- dataTable -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: This one did the job for me! Just had to mark the "right" properties as "!important" as well, otherwise the icons would overlap. Also, I changed the "font-size" property in both cases (also marking as "!important") to increase the size of the icons.